# java program to add up even number to 1

Tags: java

I need help doing a program to add up even integers to 1

I need the computer to work out 1 + 3 + 7 + 13 + 21.... + n

n is whatever the user wants it to be

The sequence is adding up each even number, so for example, you start from 1 and add 2, which gets 3, then to 3 add 4, which gets 7, then to 7 add 6, which gets 13 and so on until you get to n.

I had a complete guess

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Odd4 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JButton button;
    private JPanel panel;


    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Odd4 frame = new Odd4();
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.createLine();
        frame.show();
    }    
    private void createLine() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container window=getContentPane();
        window.setLayout (new FlowLayout());

        button = new JButton("OK");
        window.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);

    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        int n;
        int sum = 0; 
        int i;
        int s = 1;
        String nString;
        nString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("n:");
        n = Integer.parseInt(nString);
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i ++){
            if (i%2 == 0)

        do {
            j=j+i;
            sum = sum + j;
        }
        while (j <= n);      
     }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total is: " + sum);
 }
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @user3533531 we've got plenty of things, but what is the question?

Comment: Do you mean odd or even? 1, 3, 5 e.t.c is odd.

Comment: I mean you keep on adding even number (in ascending order to one)

Comment: You want to calculate (1+2)+(1+2+4)+(1+2+4+6)+(1+2+4+6+8)...?

Comment: yes @Pphoenix, that is exactly what I want

Comment: Try calculate the value with recursion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you want something like this:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    long total = 1;
    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        total += (2*i);
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

In my test it prints out:

> 1
>
> 3
>
> 7
>
> 13
>
> 21
>
> 31
>
> 43
>
> 57
>
> 73
>
> 91

**EDIT: solution to add the terms up**

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    long total = 0;
    long term = 1;
    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        term += (2*i);
        total += term;
        System.out.println("Term " + i + " is " + term);
        System.out.println("Current Total is " + total);
    }
}
```

> Term 0 is 1
>
> Current Total is 1
>
> Term 1 is 3
>
> Current Total is 4
>
> Term 2 is 7
>
> Current Total is 11
>
> Term 3 is 13
>
> Current Total is 24
>
> Term 4 is 21
>
> Current Total is 45

**EDIT: Added complete solution on Ideone**

As per the request fo the OP in the comments, I threw together a complete solution in Ideone. [It's here!](https://ideone.com/MjEBJo)

Comment: that is more or less what I want, but I want the computer to add all those numbers up

Comment: You can add this number instead of printing them ;) it is magic !

Comment: @user3533531 My first solution calculated the terms, I've added an edit that adds up the terms as it goes along too. I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: @user3533531 I'm not sure what your termination condition is. In [this example on ideone](https://ideone.com/MjEBJo) I've assumed that n is the term number you want to calculate to. So providing n=2 will give you 11. Term 0 is 1, Term 1 is 3, Term 2 is 7, so 1+3+7=11

Comment: no, n is what the final number is, so if n was 7, you would do 1 + 3 + 7, n is not what term you want to calculate to

Comment: @user3533531 Rightio, I've fixed it in that case. Again, [the code is on this ideone](https://ideone.com/MjEBJo). You should keep in mind the fact that if you put in a number that isn't in the sequence, you'll still get an answer that is likely wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much, but if you type in a number that isn't in the sequence, the answer is wrong

Comment: Can I ask why the code is wrong if you type in a number that isn't in the sequence?

Comment: @user3533531 Yep, I said that in my previous comment. Basically, since you didn't ask us to handle a scenario where the value of n isn't part of the sequence, I haven't, you should be able to put a check in for the provided value of n. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader though.

Comment: Can you please type the correct code so that if you type in a value that isn't in the sequence, it still comes up with the right answer?

Comment: Sorry, but can you explain again why when you type in a number that isn't in a sequence it comes up with the wrong answer?

Comment: @user3533531 What do you expect to happen when the provided value of n isn't in the sequence? (Sequence is 1,3,7,13,21,...  What if the provided n value is 5?)

Comment: @user3533531 without any response, I've made some tweaks and added some extra features. [Check it out here](https://ideone.com/nWXNKK). It'll handle null entries and values of n that aren't numbers and it will tell you if the n value wasn't in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

And even number can be written 2i and an odd number 2i+1.

So i am not sure about your problem but for doing the sum you make a loop increasing i and sum until your number reach n :

**Edit :** correct (sum start to 1 and add even):

```
   i = 0;
   sum = 1;
   while (2*i <= n){ // or 2*i +1 for odd

          sum += 2*i;
          i++;
   }
```

**Edit2:** the correct answer
public class HelloWorld{

```
 public static void main(String []args){

     int i=0;
     int n=7;
     int sum=1;
     int total = 0;
     while (sum < n){ // or 2*i +1 for odd

      sum += 2*i;
      total += sum;
      i++;
    }

     System.out.println(total);
   }
}
```

Comment: PLease validate this answer if it helps you ;)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is right, when I typed in 7, the answer showed was 16, but the correct answer is 14

Comment: The formula is wrong (it does 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 +... instead of 1 + 3 + 7 + 13 + ...)

Comment: replace 2*i +1 by 2*1 and start sum to 1;

Comment: This is still wrong, because when I typed in 7, it came up with 13, the correct answer is 11

Comment: @user43968 formula still looks incorrect to me (you are calculating 1 + 0 + 2 + 4 + ...

Comment: 10 minutes ago the correct result for the same input value was 14 and now it's 11, are you sure of your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need a loop to solve this.

Each term is 1 plus the sum of even number e.g. 1, 1 + 2, 1 + 2 + 4, 1 + 2 + 4 + 6.

The sum of even numbers is `x*(x+1)` and plus 1 makes `n^2 + n + 1`.

Then you want to sum these terms.

The sum of squares is `n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6`

The sum of numbers is `n*(n+1)/2`

The sum of 1, (n+1) times is `n+1`

The solution is

```
n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6 + n*(n+1)/2 + n + 1
```

or

```
(2*n^3 + 7*n^2 + 10*n + 6)/6
```

e.g

```
1 + 3 + 7 + 13 + 21 = 45
```

21 is the 4th term so

```
(2*4^3 + 7*4^2 + 10*4 + 6)/6 = 45
```

---

Using the formula and looking at the differences, and differences of differences

```
term    sum   value   even
 0        1     1       
 1        4     3       2   
 2       11     7       4   2
 3       24     13      6   2
 4       45     21      8   2
 5       76     31      10  2
 6      119     43      12  2
 7      176     57      14  2
 8      249     73      16  2
 9      340     91      18  2
10      451     111     20  2
```

Comment: n isn't what term you go up to, it's the final number you reach,

Comment: for example, if the user made n 7, the computer would do 1 + 3 + 7

Comment: @user3533531 `n` is whatever you define it to be. You can call it `i` as Dan Temple did.  What would you do if the user types 6?

Answer (score 0):

will this help?

```
int a[];
int i=0,f=1,a=2.sum=0;
while(f<=n)
{
 a[i]=f;
 f=f+a;
 a=a+2;
 i++;
}

for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++)
{
 sum+=a[j];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Terms can be written like that [image: term]:

- [image: i=0]
- [image: i=1]
- [image: i=3]
- [image: i=3]
- [image: i=3]
- ...

So you need to sum these terms while they are less than user input `n`:

```
int i=0, n = userInput, term;
int sum=0;
while((term = (i*(i+1)+1)) < n) {
    sum+=term;
    i++;
}
```

You can see it working in [this ideone](http://ideone.com/vb10ea)

Comment: n is not what term you calculate to, it's what the final number is, so for example, if n was 7, you would do 1 + 3 + 7

Comment: This is what I've done, take a look at the ideone ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want I think:-

**sumofEven** will give you the sum of numbers at even places.

```
public class Sample {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    long n =21 ;
    int i= 0;
    long sumofEven =0;
    long sumofAll =1;
    while(sumofAll <= n){
        sumofAll = (long) (sumofAll + 2*i);
        System.out.println("->"+sumofAll);
        if((i+1) % 2 == 0){
            sumofEven = sumofEven + sumofAll;
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("sumofAll Numbers : "+sumofAll +"\nSum of no at event place : "+sumofEven);
}
```

}