# Correct java program to add up even numbers to 1

Tags: java

I need help doing a program to add up even integers to 1

I need the computer to work out 1 + 3 + 7 + 13 + 21.... + n

n is whatever the user wants it to be and is the final number of the sequence, for example, if you make n 7, the computer does 1 + 3 + 7

The sequence is adding up each even number, so for example, you start from 1 and add 2, which gets 3, then to 3 add 4, which gets 7, then to 7 add 6, which gets 13 and so on until you get to n.

This is what I've got, but for some reason, if you type in a number that is not in the sequence the answer is wrong. If you make n 7, you get 11, which is right, but if you make n 8 you get 26, it is wrong. Can anyone correct it?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Odd4 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JButton button;
    private JPanel panel;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Odd4 frame = new Odd4();
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.createLine();
        frame.show();
    }

    private void createLine() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container window=getContentPane();
        window.setLayout (new FlowLayout());

        button = new JButton("OK");
        window.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        int n;
        String nString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("n:");
        n = Integer.parseInt(nString);

        int total = 0;
        int term = 1;
        int i = 0;
        while( term < n ) {
            term += (2*i);
            total = total + term;
            i++;

        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total is: " + total);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079296/java-program-to-add-up-even-number-to-1

Comment: When you enter 8, would you expect 7 to be the last number in the sequence? Since 8 would not be in the sequence but your requirement is  "n is whatever the user wants it to be and is the final number of the sequence"

Comment: what do you mean by "wrong"? what are you getting for n=8? what should it be?

Comment: Please don't ask essentially the same question 3 times. It is very easy to spot duplicates.

Comment: Do you know how to correct the code?

Comment: When you do n = 8, it should get 11, but it gets 26

Comment: @user3533531 btw are you sure you do not get 24, not 26

Comment: It is 24, sorry, calculation error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the cycle you chould add a check to only add `term` if it is not greater than `n`:

```
    while( term < n ) {
        term += (2*i);
        if (term > n) {
          break;
        }
        total = total + term;
        i++;

    }
```

In the case you mention, you enter 8, the term is 7 and than as 7 is less than 8 , you enter the cycle, you compute the new term and add it(although it is greater than 8).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the formula for an arithmetic series

[image: enter code here]

or

[image]